# Decode unicode to string in django template

Tags: python, django, mongodb, unicode, scrapy

I'm trying to loop through a database and output the results in a django template. I got all that working but it outputs every item as the following in the html:

> [u'AMD', u'A10-7700K, 3,4 GHz (3,8 GHz Turbo Boost) FM2+ processor']
>
> [u'\n 3.400 MHz\xa0\n ', u'\n 4 cores\xa0\n ', u'\n FM2+\xa0\n ']

For the record. I want it to output as a normal string without the unicode. I tried a bunch of things but none of it seems to work. I would write down all the things I've tried but I honestly can't even keep track of all of it.

I got the following django files, I'll only write down the relevant pieces:

views.py:

```
def processoren(request):

    processoren = Processoren.objects(categorie__contains='Processor')[:10]
    #processoren = json.dumps(list(processoren)
    return render_to_response('processoren.html', {'Processoren': processoren},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from mongoengine import *
from APc.settings import DBNAME

connect(DBNAME)

    class Processoren(Document):
    categorie = StringField(max_length=120)
    naam = StringField(max_length=500)
    subnaam = StringField(max_length=500)
    info = StringField(max_length=500)
    stock = StringField(max_length=500)
    enter code hereprijs = StringField(max_length=120)
```

processoren.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">



    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">

    <div class=" top-margin">
        
        <h1>Processoren</h1>
        {% for processor in Processoren %}
        <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">                    
                <div class="row-picture">
                    <img class="square" src="http://lorempixel.com/56/56/people/1"    alt="icon">
                </div>

                <div class="row-content">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ processor.naam }}</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ processor.info }}</p>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text pull-right">{{ processor.prijs }}</p>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text pull-right">{{ processor.stock }}</p>
                </div>

            </div>



        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>


</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to simply just put str() after processor.naam for example but that doesn't work either. What does work is adding 0 after processor.naam but then I of course only get the first index which would be "AMD". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this line: `processoren = Processoren.objects(categorie__contains='Processor')[:10]` isn't `processoren = Processoren.objects.filter(categorie__contains='Processor')[:10]` ?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what .filter() does but it sadly gives the same result.

Comment: Are you using the non-rel branch of Django? or ?

Comment: No, at least not as far as I know. I use mongoengine to connect to the mongodb.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using that engine. I could show you a way to convert the unicode values to strings, but I'm not sure that's the best way to address the root of the problem.

Comment: Alright thanks for the input. Nevertheless I would really appreciate it if you could explain that to me. Even though it won't solve the root problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there no way to just go through the unicode value so to speak. Since it does properly output processor.naam.0 . I tried for example processor.naam.0:5 but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure. Unfortunately I don't have time to go dig into the MongoEngine queryset operations, but I'm sure you'll get some additional answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Unicode. You have a list of items, you need to iterate through them.

```
{% for name in processor.naam %}{{ name }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yea I figured that along the way but I can't figure out how to iterate trough them in a django template. I tried for example processor.naam.0:5 but that doesn't work. I can't find any relevant documentation either. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: I've posted an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with MongoEngine in regards to Django, it's fairly simple to convert your unicode values to strings, which will hopefully get you by for the time being until you can address the root of the problem.

```
objects = Processoren.objects.filter(categorie__contains='Processor')[:10]
processoren = [str(p.naam) for p in objects]
```

Again, I don't know what methods are available on the query set using that engine, so I've avoided using `values_list` in this case. Wasn't sure which property you needed to output either so I just used `naam`

Comment: This at least gives me a little boost. Thanks a ton!